# how to reduce if statements in javascript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm writing code in vanilla JavaScript but I don't want to write a thousand different if statements.

I already tried searching up how to reduce if statements in JavaScript, but I didn't find anything helpful.

Here is some example code:

```
if (a == "text" && b == "othertext") {
  console.log("message");
} else if (a == "text2" && b == "othertext2") {
  console.log("other message");
} else if (a == "text3" && b == "othertext3") {
  console.log("other other message");
} else if (a == "text4" && b == "othertext4") {
  console.log("other other other message");
} else if (a == "text5" && b == "othertext5") {
  console.log("other other other other message");
} else if (a == "text6" && b == "othertext6") {
  // .. and so on.
}
```

If anyone can help me, it would be appreciated

Comment: Is there any logic to what you're matching, or are they arbitrary strings?

Comment: just arbitrary strings

Comment: If you have, say 100 distinct conditions that you want to handle differently, you would have to use `if` or `switch` statements as required. I would recommend to make your question more specific and clear.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a data-driven approach by using the strings as keys in an object.

```js
const messages = {
  "text|othertext": "message",
  "text1|othertext1": "message1",
  "text2|othertext2": "message2"
};

function showMessage(a, b) {
  let key = `${a}|${b}`;
  if (messages.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log(messages[key]);
  } else {
    console.log("Invalid a and b");
  }
}

showMessage("text", "othertext");
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use ternary operators I suppose.

```
let msg = '';
msg = a === 'text' && b === 'othertext' : msg;
msg = a === 'text2' && b === 'othertext2' : msg; 
// etc.
```

Ultimately its not gonna get much prettier but that might be a little bit simpler to type.